# How to click page link in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get data on [this page](https://eproperty.casey.vic.gov.au/T1PRProd/WebApps/eProperty/P1/eTrack/eTrackApplicationSearchResults.aspx?Field=S&Period=TM&r=P1.WEBGUEST&f=%24P1.ETR.SEARCH.STM).
As you can see, there are 5 pages and I want to click these links one by one and then get the data of the table.
But I can't move to the next page.
My codes are likes below.

```
page_counts = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[@class='pagerRow']/td/table/tbody/tr/td"))
next_page_no = 2
while True:
    ... 
    try:
       element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@class='pagerRow']/td/table/tbody/tr/td[" + str(next_page_no) + "]/a")
       driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
       next_page_no += 1
       time.sleep(2)
    except:
       break
```

How can I click the each page link? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I haven't tested this but after this line:
`element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@class='pagerRow']/td/table/tbody/tr/td[" + str(next_page_no) + "]/a")`

you should be able to use `element.click()` method if the element you found is clickable.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I also used that method before, but the result is the same.

Comment: Hmm, so what happens when you try to click? Nothing or does it give an error?

Comment: oh.. sorry, that was my fault. It works fine and the issue is in other code in while loop. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Demo

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://eproperty.casey.vic.gov.au/T1PRProd/WebApps/eProperty/P1/eTrack/eTrackApplicationSearchResults.aspx?Field=S&Period=TM&r=P1.WEBGUEST&f=%24P1.ETR.SEARCH.STM')

current_page = 1
while True:
    pager = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('tr.pagerRow')
    links = pager.find_elements_by_xpath(f"//a[text()='{current_page+1}']")
    if not links:
        break

    a = links[0]
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(a).perform()
    a.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    current_page += 1

driver.quit()
```